# Views Slideshow Stops Working Alongside Other Slideshows

Tags: blocks, views

I've made several thumbnail-sized cycle slideshows as block views, which display fields from nodes created via an HTML feed. Each slideshow is basically the same, but they all use a different taxonomy term as a filter on a single content type, and have a different XPath parsing structure.

The slideshows work perfectly on each view's preview page. Each also works separately when its block is displayed on the main page. I've managed to get 6 slideshows at once scrolling normally as blocks on the main page.

However, when I display a 7th slideshow in a block on the main page, only two slideshows work properly, with the rest not progressing via time or clicking on the controls. If I add an 8th slideshow block, 3 of them work, and the other 5 do not.

The 7th and 8th slideshows have slightly different field output, as the feed source is configured differently, but I don't think this is relevant, as the view-generated HTML looks the same.

I can get sporadic results by re-arranging the blocks in the block list, and by displaying them in different block areas. Some permutations allow all the slideshows to function, some only allow a few.

Is there a limit to the number of JQuery slideshows that can be running at once? Or, is there maybe some kind of naming convention that's causing these mixed results with different ordering?

Totally confused, and disappointed. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some inspired messing around, I determined that the issue only stopped slideshows that were displayed after a certain slideshow. Using that information, I deleted the isolated block, and re-created it in the same form as the other slideshows.

This appears to have solved the problem. I guess something was corrupt with that particular view. It was the one I was originally using as a clone base for all the other slideshow blocks.

Hopefully this "fix" persists!